# ApexChart - axis with very small numbers

Tags: apexcharts

I'm trying to generate a chart which deals with very small numbers. However the x-axis (actually the y-axis as it's a horizontal stacked bar chart) on ApexCharts displays only zeroes, which has the effect of hiding some data bars.

I've tried

```
yaxis: {
 type: 'numeric',
 tickAmount: 50
},
```

...and...

```
yaxis: {
 type: 'numeric',
 tickAmount: 'dataPoints'
},
```

... but neither works (the second option crashes the browser!)

A very basic example with not very much data at all:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxojwZ

If you toggle between the dates (using the date options at the bottom you'll see the extra data which is not (but should be) displayed by default.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an older version of ApexCharts (2.2.4).
I suggest you replace it with the latest version by using this CDN link - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts

Here is the updated configuration for the chart

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: "bar",
    stacked: true,
    height: 300
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      barHeight: "90%",
      distributed: true,
      horizontal: true
    }
  },
  stroke: {
    width: 1,
    colors: ["#fff"]
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Monday 7th January 2019",
      data: [0.02, 0.01, 0.01]
    },
    {
      name: "Tuesday 8th January 2019",
      data: [0.02, 0.01, 0.01]
    },
    {
      name: "Wednesday 9th January 2019",
      data: [0.01, 0.02, 0.0]
    }
  ],
  xaxis: {
    categories: ["England", "Scotland", "Wales"],
    title: {
      text: "Average"
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return val;
      }
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yaxis: {},
  tooltip: {
    theme: "light",
    x: {
      show: true
    }
  }
};
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#statChart"), options);
chart.render();
```

which produces this result
[image: ApexCharts - Bar chart with small values]

Working [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/QYwpyG)